# Creating function that is coloring a table cell if it contains a certain value

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, handlebars.js, bootstrap-4

I am working on a table for a CI testing website. If the automatic tests are finding any bugs, a variable with the numbers if errors are pushed to the table (created in Bootstrap 4), the color of all the cells that are affected should turn red. If the value of the variable is 0, the affected table cells should turn green. The same with Style errors... Since this is a Node application, I am using handlebars (.hbs).

I think the best approach is to have a jQuery function that is "listening" to the incoming values and then is coloring each table that has a single 0 or a single 1, but I don't know how to implement this! I am using the CDN from https://cdn.datatables.net/.

How do I do I this and is there any better approach that is preferable in this case?

**Results.hbs** (where the table is created). With {{{insertRow}}} the data in the table is generated from index.js file:

```
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="resultsTable">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered">
                    <thead id="semiBlackHead">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">Project</th>
                        <th class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">Last push</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2ths col-xs-6">Bugs</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2ths col-xs-6">Style errors</th>
                        <th class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="bleachedBody">
                    {{{insertRow}}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script>

    $(function () {
        if (("cBugs". value === 0)) {
            document.getElementById("cBugs").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("cBugs").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        }
    });

</script>
```

**Index.js**, which are pushing data to results.hbs:

```
router.get('/results', function (req, res, next) {
    //Getting Jenkins jobs
    dataGetter.getAllJobs('http://10.2.2.33:8080');

    //Builds the table and then renders the results site
    exports.loadJobs = function (jobsList) {
        var table = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < jobsList.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6" id="cProject">' + jobsList[i].name + '</td>' +
                '<td class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6"  id="cPush"><b>' + 'Date: ' + '</b>' + jobsList[i].lastPushDate + '<br><b>' + 'Comment: ' + '</b>' + jobsList[i].lastCommitComment + '</td>' +
                '<td class="col-md-2ths col-xs-6" id="cBugs" >' + jobsList[i].findbugs + '</td>' +
                '<td class="col-md-2ths col-xs-6" id="cStyle" >' + jobsList[i].checkstyle + '</td>' +
                '<td class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6" id="cDetails" >' +  'null' + '</td></tr>' ;
        }
        res.render('results', {title: 'reportsite', insertRow: table});
    };

});
```

**CSS** (the Datatables CDN)

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:before, table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
    padding: 5px;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .mdb-select {
    border: none;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .mdb-select.form-control {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-left: 0.7rem;
    margin-right: 0.7rem;
}

.dataTables_length label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
}

.dataTables_filter label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dataTables_filter label input.form-control {
    margin-top: -0.6rem;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

table.dataTable {
    margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_info {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique throughout the whole page, so using IDs to mark your cells is problematic. You have no idea how the browser will handle it, but most likely not as you intended.

Comment: better add a class to the cells and define a style like `table.hilightBugs td.bug { background: red }` so you can switch hilighting on/off for all cells at once by simply toggling the class on the table itself.

Comment: That's great @davidkonrad! I will check the links you posted!

Comment: @josefdev, most of the samples is based on JSON and dataTables rendering, but the technique is the same, see **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell**